# SharePoint -customized contact form

Tags: sharepoint

I am working on WSS 3.0. I am requiring to develop a custom contact form -requirements are very specific so I would like to code it.

What options do I have? Could I use the Form Web Part?

Thank you for your valuable help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is probably best to create a custom web part, especially if you have some specific requirements. This will give you an option to develop it just the way you want it